# NSDate & NSFormatter issues in Amman, Jordan

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

My device timezone is set to Amman, Jordan. This code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"20130329"];
NSLog(@"date: %@, timezone: %@", date, [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]);
```

Results in this log:

```
date: (null), timezone: Asia/Amman (GMT+02:00) offset 7200
```

Assumingly because of DST in Amman, Jordan, this date and time doesn't exist. But then this code:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
components.year = 2013;
components.month = 03;
components.day = 29;
NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
NSLog(@"date: %@, timezone: %@", date, [calendar timeZone]);
```

Results in this log:

```
date: 2013-04-28 21:00:00 +0000, timezone: Asia/Amman (GMT+02:00) offset 7200
```

Why?

Comment: The problem could be in timezones `[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"..."]];`

Comment: That's not it... see my updated log edits.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine and no error what so ever, clear the target and check again.

See [here](http://www.timehall.com/time/Jordan/P9C)

Comment: What version of iOS? I'm still seeing (null) in iOS6.0.1

Comment: Sorry, I checked it in mac osx, now checked it in ios6.0. I wonder what is the differnce between osx and ios timezone and daylight!!!!